# Potential Security Risk of Browser Coded in Python

Tags: python, security, browser, ads

I'm busy programming a personal browser in python for day-to-day use and potentially to replace other browsers on my rig i.e firefox and chrome.
I'd just gotten the basic framework down and opened google on it to test, when the first site I opened flooded me with ads which got me wondering.
Are there any potential security threats I'm opening myself up to by using a homemade browser and what kind of prevention measures would one of these established companies put into place to protect there users? Above and beyond personal AV software of course.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Mainly using pyqt5 for the base and adding packages as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module called 'woob' - web outside of browser which it is said that "Its nice project for non-sensitive data but a big fat watering hole target for financial info."  Which is a module that could be updated , like the `requests` module that could be updated with theft features , and thats the problem - the use of another module that you have no control over for sensitive data.
The measures you could take is that current modules are intact and secure , and monitor any updates or prevent updates .

Comment: Ah perfect thanks. So in other words should be fine as long as I don't use it for financial or other sensitive data